# Chris Richards' jQuery half rating

Tags: jquery, rating

I am trying to use the [Chris Richards jQuery rating](http://zensoftware.org/archives/483) and I have found it very useful and simple to use, but I need to have half ratings as well which the plugin doesn't have. Is there any modification to have this function ?

I couldn't use [this](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/) as the file was very messy to use!

Update: What I need is 10 stars rating from 0.5 to 5 . It means that I want separate star for half rating and I need to show the selected rating on click .

Thanks

Comment: Just as friendly bit of information ;) if it were me I'd go for a vote style system like StackOverflow for the following reasons - http://xkcd.com/1098/

Comment: What do you mean by show? as in numbers or in stars? because it shows the selected stars right after you click em

Answer (score 2):

I suggest http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/ its pretty nice, I use it and I even developed a Zend framework form element for it, I would recommend it, you can split as much as you want

It have got more features, I don't think you would want to modify it, it has got readOnly, and dynamicly set the rating, if you have got dependencies on rating criteria you can calculate it and et it just easily

A pretty basic examples would be:

```
 // selects radio with value 3
 $('.myclass').rating('select',3);
 $('.myclass').rating('readOnly',true);
 $('.myclass').rating('disable');
```

To split the stars you will need to do the following

```
<input class="myclass {split:2}" />
```

And split as much as you want, you will need to double the radio buttons because each one will be a half start from 0.5 in case of split 2, for instance the sequence would be 0.5,1,1.5 ...etc instead of 1,2,3....etc

---

**Update**:

for locking you can set it as readonly like the following

```
$('.myclass').rating({
    callback: function(value, link){
    // mark it readonlyHere most probably like this $(this).readOnly(true)
}
});
```

Comment: FYI that's the one OP described as "messy to use" :-)  To me it looks quite nice and well documented tho.

Comment: Hi Shaaban, I tried to use that but index file in the package is not available anymore and there is documentation.html file which is the whole plugin documentation . So it is hard to find a piece and test it.Moreover I need the result to be shown on click on the stars.

Comment: Their documentation is scattered, and its annoying a bit, but if you open the source file you will find the methods/documentation, and their examples are in api and demos

Comment: Do you any solution for clicking on the star and when the rate is locked showing the result?

Comment: Do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution can be like this:
I used rateit plugin  http://rateit.codeplex.com/ instead .

```
<div class="rateit" id="rateit5" data-rateit-min="0" data-rateit-max="10" 
data-rateit- step="1"></div>
<div>
<span id="value5"></span>
<span id="hover5"></span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#rateit5").bind('rated', function (event, value) 
    { $('#value5').text('You\'ve     rated it: ' + value/2); });
    $("#rateit5").bind('reset', function () 
    { $('#value5').text('Rating reset'); });
    $("#rateit5").bind('over', function (event, value) { 
        if (value == null)
        $('#hover5').text();
        else    
        $('#hover5').text(' ' + value/2); });
</script>
```